# Unable to resolve module 'module://AssetRegistry.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-native

I have this simple snack expo, which was working perfectly until two days ago but now all of a sudden, it is throwing this error. I haven't changed the code at all. I believe something went wrong with the package.json file.

Here is my code: (with style sheet omitted for now)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Title, Text, Form, Item, Input, Label} from 'native-base';
import { StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

export class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container View style={styles.container}>
      <Text View style={styles.title}>
      My App</Text>
      <Form View style={styles.formInput}>
            <Item floatingLabel>
              <Label View style={styles.labelText}>Username</Label>
              <Input 
              View style={styles.textInput}
              value={this.state.username}
          onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
          placeholder={'Username'}
          />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel last>
              <Label View style={styles.labelText}>Password</Label>
              <Input 
              View style={styles.textInput}
              value={this.state.password}
          onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
          placeholder={'Password'}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          />
            </Item>
          </Form>
          <Left>
            <Button View style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Details")}>
              <Text>Login</Text>
            </Button>
            <Text View style={styles.forgotText} >
            Forgot Password?</Text>
          </Left>
          <Right>
            <Button hasText transparent>
              <Text
              View style={styles.signupText}
              >Don't have an account? Sign Up</Text>
            </Button>
          </Right>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
    );
  }
}

const LoginRouter = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Login },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },       
  }
)

export default createAppContainer(LoginRouter);
```

This is my Package.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-paper": "3.1.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "2.0.16",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.20",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "native-base": "2.13.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it looks like it's a problem with snacks. After running locally, my project worked as expected. Here is a link to the ticket I opened on expo forums: https://forums.expo.io/t/module-assetregistry-js/32650

Comment: The weird thing is that it was working one day but completely stopped the next day, even though I didn't change the code at all!

Comment: Yeah same for me. I think it is something the expo team will have to fix because it's likely a problem with how the snack runs your code. The expo team had me run my code locally. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I'm not on "Web" view on snack.. either iOS/Android works perfectly. It's a bug 'cause they possibly couldn't export 'react-navigation' and 'react-navigation-stack' to web version yet..